# Vertical Gallery implementation using ListViews

Tags: android, listview

We have to implement a vertical Gallery of objects (say static text) with fixed focus at the center of screen. Focus will stay at one point and the items will scroll up and down. The list will start from the center of screen.
Questions:

1. Can this be done using ListView? How?
2. Or will I have to extend Gallery object and work on orientation?

Comment: vertical scrolling is desired plus i need view recycling too...:)

Comment: oops sorry ! I meant vertical srollview :) deleted the older comment !

Comment: please check my simple solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639958/how-i-can-create-vertical-gallery-in-android/15358307#15358307

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gallery will not allow vertical scrolling, only horizontal. For that reason, I don't think your second question has a working answer. I recently needed to accomplish something along these lines and found this to be helpful: http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/