# Android - make a Gallery scrolling vertically

Tags: android, gallery, vertical-scrolling

Here is my issue : I'd like to make a Gallery scrolling vertically on android.

I found many topics where the answer was to make a listView. 
In my case it's not a solution.

In fact, I work on an application already available on the store. I have to do an update of this app making it compatible with tablet. 
For that, the gallery horizontal for phones have to be vertical for tablets.

How can I change the gallery properties to do that ?

I apologize for my broken English

Comment: I finally found a helpful topic few months ago : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455196/vertical-gallery-implementation-using-listviews

Answer (score 0):

i think gallery view never allow the vertical view better do something like taking vertical linearlayout with in the scrollview