# Android: ImageView using scaleType="matrix" sample practical usage (to help me understand the matrix scaletype)

Tags: android, imagemap

Would you help me to understand ImageView using scaleType="matrix"...
By providing some practical usage.

Want to create a Building Floor Plan Map. Maps are still images of each floor plan of a building.

Use Case:

1. set the current & destination place. (e.g. current:1F destination:5F)
2. current floor will be shown. scroll up & down to move to other floors.

My first step is to show the current floor image then switch to other by scrolling.
Guide me on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think GalleryView will solve your problem. Normally Gallery View display images in Horizontally but you can set it vertically.

Vertical Gallery View

- [Vertical gallery in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056760/vertical-gallery-in-android)
- [How I can create vertical gallery in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639958/how-i-can-create-vertical-gallery-in-android)